# Method to get all declared rules from jQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

How can I loop in JS through jQuery validation required fields? Particularly I want to add the `.required` css class to them.

EDIT:

Here is a sample code:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        'firstName': "required",
        'lastName': "required",
         #{get 'jsValidation' /} // some rules come from outside
    }
});
```

I just need to loop through the form fields that are marked "required" in jQuery.validate and add a css class (for example `.my_required`) to them.

**Important note!** not all jQuery.validate required fields have the `.required` css class.

Comment: Using jQuery `.each()` and `.addClass()`??  What have you tried?  Where is your code?  Why do you need to do this?  If they're already `required`, then why are you adding the `required` class?  The jQuery Validate plugin adds/removes the valid/invalid classes automatically... is this what you're talking about?  See [this page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for the options.

Comment: I cannot change the html directly as it is auto-generated. I need to add the `.required` for styling. Some of the jQuery.validate "required" fields have the `.required` css class, some don't, and I need to add this class to those that don't have it. The jQuery.validate rules have been built manually, not using the `.required` css class. Hopefully this clarifies my need.

Comment: **You did not show us anything**.  How are we supposed to know how to target the fields that don't already have the `required` class.  Otherwise, simply attach `.addClass("required")` to the appropriate jQuery selector... have you tried that yet?   You should also realize that adding the `required` class will automatically make the field "required" as per the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: do you have access to the css?  you could just add a `[required]` to the existing `.required` styling css i.e.: `input[type='text'].required, input[type='text'][required] {...}`

Comment: Using `.addClass("required")` through the fields selector would need more coding in several files, and I do not have direct access to the fields list that are required (specific implementation details). The simplest way is that I can just loop though the jQuery.validate required fields.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you construct a solution when **YOU HAVE NOT SHOWN US ANYTHING**?   How would we know they are "required" if they don't already have the class?  You really do need to fix the question so that it contains the relevant code and explanation.  As it stands, there is more information in your first comment than in the question itself.

Comment: If you can't use a jQuery selector and `.addClass()`, then **there is no solution.**  There is no method in this plugin for translating the `required` rule into a `required` class.

Comment: Hmm.. ok :(. I thought there shall be a way to get the list of field required rules from the Js validator.

Comment: The object literal contained within the `.validate()` method contains the list of rules.  The plugin developer probably did not see the point in creating a method that outputs something you should have configured in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, but the list of rules is built dynamically in my case. Anyway thanks for your input so far. I can handle it, though the option to get a list of rules from the validator would have helped me a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's built dynamically, but then most developers have enough access to simply include the necessary CSS when the dynamic fields are created.  The fact that some fields already contain the `required` class says that you should re-examine how your HTML is created.

Comment: @Sparky you can answer my question saying that there is no solution, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Okay, then.  I did my best to consolidate my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no method as part of the jQuery Validate plugin that will return the list of declared, defined, or assigned rules back to you.  However, the object literal contained within the `.validate()` method contains a list of fields and their assigned rules.

```
console.log($("#myForm").validate().settings.rules);
```

A field's `class` and HTML5 attributes within the HTML can also contain rules that are picked up and used by the jQuery Validate plugin.

*(The plugin developer probably did not see the point in creating a method just to output something you typically would have configured, therefore known, in the first place.)*

> "I just need to loop through the form fields that are marked "required" in jQuery.validate and add a css class"

If some fields have the `required` rule as per the `.validate()` method and other fields have the `required` rule as per the `.required` class, there is no technique for returning/selecting *all* fields that are "required".  So if you cannot simply use a clever jQuery selector and the `.addClass()` method, there is no solution.

*(Actually, the best solution would be to take control the HTML so that the `required` rule is declared consistently throughout the project... either via the `.validate()` method OR the HTML `class` attribute, not a mix of both.)*

Answer (score 2):

The rules object is located after the validator `settings` like so:

```
var myValidator = $('form').validate({rules: {'name': { 'required' : true } } });

console.log(myValidator.settings.rules); // outputs current rules
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// add class to anything with required attr
$('[required="required"]').addClass('required');
```

I agree with the dude in the comment though, this seem redundant.

Comment: I have a feeling that's not really what he wants.  Unfortunately, the OP will have to fix his question before we'll know.

Comment: I agree. He was pretty vague. I figured it was worth giving him what he wanted though and he can use it as he pleases.

Comment: Making guesses does not really help the community though.  Notice that your solution was originally my idea that I posted as a comment instead of an answer.  Until the question is fixed, the OP should not be indulged, IMO.

Comment: I cannot use a selector as there is no consistency (`.required` class or `required` prop) among the Js.validate required fields.

Answer (score -1):

```
var settings = $.data($("#myForm")[0], "validator").settings
console.log(settings.rules)
```

find attribute 'required'

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.